# What could these spots on my bearded dragon's nose be?

Tags: health, reptiles, bearded-dragon, molting

I noticed a few days ago that my bearded dragon has a couple spots on her nose and mouth area. I thought that it was dirt but it didn't wash off. Has anyone got any ideas what it could be?

[image][image]

Comment: is it possible for you to add some more details to your question,like the age and how long you have had the pet gender might allso help.